# Free App for Paid Service

Tags: security, appexchange, app, security-review, website-integration

I'm working on getting an app listed on the AppExchange, and we are just about ready to go into the Security Review. We were wondering if it is going to be a problem that we sell our app for free on the AppExchange, but to get our (required) web service a subscription is required. How does that work as far as paying for the security review and getting it passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things come to mind, The first and most important is are you a registered ISV? If not I think you should [join right away](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/).

Being a registered ISV means you have someone within Salesforce that you can talk to about these kind of issues.

I just went and took a look at one of the apps we currently have in security review and the help text regarding paid or free apps is as follows:

> Indicate if you charge for your app or if it is free for all to use. Free downloads, free trials and pay-per-use apps are considered paid.
>   For paid apps, we will collect a fee.

I read this as, despite your app being free on the app exchange you still charge for it elsewhere, making it a paid app as far as Salesforce is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that was helpful! Do you have any ideas about sharing revenue with Salesforce with this setup?

Comment: Talk to your ISV rep